# Right click in listview in order for contextmenustrip to be shown , but the popup menu is appearing in an irrelevant point of the screen

Tags: vb.net, listview, contextmenu, right-click

Using the above vb.net code i have managed to show a popup contextmenustrip when i right click a selected item of a listview.

```
Private Sub ListViewResults_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListViewResults.MouseUp
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            lvChangedFilesMenuStrip.Show(ListView1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Regarding the second parameter of the lvChangedFilesMenuStrip.show method i have tried

1. `New Point(e.X, e.Y)`
2. `Cursor.Position`
3. `e.X, e.Y`

.. and i see that the popup is still apearing in an irrelevant point of the screen !
What sould i do in order  the contextmenu to be shown right down of the clicked point ?

Comment: I can never remember which way around it is, but you probably want to look at Control.PointToClient or Control.PointToScreen.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient?view=net-5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you not see an issue between this:

```vb
Handles ListViewResults.MouseUp
```

and this

```vb
Show(ListView1
```

You're handling an event of one control, so the coordinates provided by the event handler are relative to that control, and then you display your menu relative to a different control.